# Wordpress - Disable user notification on password change

Tags: wordpress, email, notifications, forgot-password

Our client wants to disable the default notification email that sends Wordpress when someone uses the "forgot password" form.

The client uses a theme that also sends out an email with the new password so the default notification should be disabled.

But I don't know how to do this, can anyone help me with this?

Regards

Answer (score 7):

Add this line to your function file to disable default password change notification in wordpress.

To disable the notice of changed email sent by the wp_update_user() function, simply use the filter hook to return false:

```
add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Reference - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/send_email_change_email

**Method 2**

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_password_change_notification() {}
}
```

put this code in your plugin file for method 2.
Note - it will not work if you put in your theme function file

Reference - http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-lostchanged-password-emails-in-wordpress/

**Method 3 - use this plugin to get required output**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/manage-notification-emails/

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it keeps sending out the email notification with subject "Message about password change".

Comment: Try method 2 and check

Comment: Unfortunately I still get 2 notifications. I did the option with the code snippet plugin or do I really need to make a plugin?

Comment: Try method 3 if you don't want to create plugin. else in method 2 its good if you can create custom plugin